# iTunes 12: How to cycle through View Options with script/shortcut?

Tags: itunes, applescript, macos

I'm trying to writing an applescript that cycles through Songs, Albums, Artists, Composers, Genres, and back to Songs.

[image: Problem]

There is nothing in applescript Dictionary with regards to this, so I have to resort to UIscripting/Accessibility. This is what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"

    set frontmost to true -- necessary
    delay 1 -- for last line to take effect, delete if you bind this to keyboard shortcut

    tell window 1 -- tell window "iTunes" only works when in fullscreen

        tell pop up button 2 to perform action "AXPress" -- equivalent of
        --keystroke "j" using {command down}

        tell UI element 1 of row 5 of table 1 of pop over 1 of pop up button 2 to perform action "AXPress"
        -- pressing Genres button, assuming Vies is not in Genres already, of course

    end tell
end tell
```

You can run this with Script Editor, or preferably for the purpose of the rest of this question, bind it to a keyboard shortcut and invoke it while in iTunes. When you run this, you see the pop up menu flash on your screen, right?

Now, here is the interesting part: Use your cursor to click the pop up button, move down and position the cursor on *Artists*.

[image: Cursor]

The cursor itself is omitted by OS X Screenshot function, but you can see *Artists* is in focus. Now press *Esc* to hide the menu, and invoke the script while the cursor in still in this position.

Bam! You now switched to *Artists* view. It turns out the 2nd `perform action "AXPress"` is performed under cursor because the pop up menu is not in focus after clicking the vie option button.

There is a simpler way to verify this problem/bug. 1) Click view option. 2) Press *Down* key a couple times. You would expect focus would move to *Songs*, and then *Albums*, right? Nope, you are just moving through library items in the background, all the while the menu is still in display in the foreground.

So, my question boils down to, *how can I move cursor focus to this pop up menu?*

**UPDATE:** Thanks @jackjr300 for the answer. This what my finished script looks like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
        tell pop up button 2 of window 1
            click

            if value of attribute "AXDescription" is "Genres" then
                tell (select row 1 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
            end if
            if value of attribute "AXDescription" is "Songs" then
                tell (select row 2 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
            end if
            if value of attribute "AXDescription" is "Albums" then
                tell (select row 3 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
            end if
            if value of attribute "AXDescription" is "Artists" then
                tell (select row 4 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
            end if
            if value of attribute "AXDescription" is "Composers" then
                tell (select row 5 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
            end if

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select` command to select the row.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true 
        delay 1
        tell pop up button 2 of window 1
            click
            tell (select row 5 of table 1 of pop over 1) to click UI element 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```